# Normal multivariate standard TIKZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, statistics

[image]

I need to perform this graph in TIKZ, there is no need to be equal, it is to be approximated.

Comment: I've downvoted the question because it does not show much effort. Did you already try something? Where did you get stuck? As it is now, you ask the members of the community here to do everything for you: setting up a document, put basic code to include a 3d TikZ graph and a 2d one, invent data or a mathematical formula to create the shape, and finetuning the appearance. Surely you can do some of this yourself - if you do you have a much better chance of getting useful answers here. Start for example with http://pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/contour-surface/.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a `just-do-it-for-me` class of question. And, I have downvoted because of the above stated reason.

Answer (score 5):

This is more or less taken from the lower example on p. 152 of the pgfplots manual. Please compile with `-shell-escape`, e.g. `pdflatex -shell-escape <file.tex>`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[domain=-2:2,domain y=-2:2]
 \addplot3 [contour gnuplot={output point meta=rawz,labels=false},z filter/.code={\def\pgfmathresult{-1}}] 
  {5*pow(max(x,0),2)*exp(-x^2-y^2)};
 \addplot3 [mesh,color=red,samples=51,samples y=51] {5*pow(max(x,0),2)*exp(-x^2-y^2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]